# Pass automator variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, applescript, automator

I'd like to use the selected text in my automator workflow. If I use `"Run bash action"` I have the option "pass input as arguments". But in the case of `"Run JavaScript"` action - I don't.

So, what should I do to pass clipboard data (text) to my JS function `sum_letters`?

[My Automator workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjVaP.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Run Javascript** in *Automator* requires the declaration of a `run()` function, which is called upon initialisation.  It's where your main code implementations are placed.  It is defined like so:

```
    function run(input, parameters) {

        // Your script goes here

        return input
    }
```

It has two arguments.  The one of interest to you is the `input` argument, which will contain any data passed through from the previous action in the workflow, stored as an array.

In your workflow, the contents of the clipboard is carried through from the **Copy to Clipboard** action, and passed into the `input` variable, which will contain a single element, `input[0]`, the value of which will be the clipboard's contents.

You can then pass this as an argument to your function `sum_letters()`.

Here's what it would look like:

**Run Javascript:**

```
    function run(input, parameters) {
        var clipboardText = input[0]
        sum_letters(clipboardText)

        // Other lines of code

        return input[0]
    }

    function num_letters(k,d) {
        var i = '', e = [

        // ...etc...
    }

    function sum_letters(t) {

        // Lines of code
    }
```

and so on.  So `run()` is called immediately when the workflow reaches the **Run Javascript** action.  Other functions, such as `num_letters()` and `sum_letters()` only get called if done so explicitly from either inside `run()`, or from inside another function that is called from `run()`.

`run()` terminates when it reaches a `return` statement.  This passes a value of your choosing back to the *Automator* workflow and onto the next action.

If you need any clarification or have further questions, let me know.

Comment: @S.A.  Yes, my apologies.  I assumed from your question and your workflow screenshots that you were a JavaScript programmer, and just needed a hint.  Bear with me, and I'll update my answer more fully.